# What codecs are supported by the different GStreamer plugin sets?

Tags: multimedia, codecs, gstreamer, plugins

- What codecs are supported by the "good" plugin set?
- What codecs are supported by the "bad" plugin set?
- What codecs are supported by the "ugly" plugin set?

I would like a list of codecs in each plugin set.

Answer (score 1):

They should be listed in the description of the package.  You can run 'apt-cache show' followed by the package name to see what is included in your release.  These can change between releases.